# Capturing CATiledLayer content to another layer or image context

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, catiledlayer

I'm trying to screen capture a view that uses CATiledLayers (for animation) but unable to get the image that I want.

I tried it on Apple's "PhotoScroller" sample application and added this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, the tiles don't render in the resulting UIImage and all I get is the tile outlines.

Seems that CATiledLayer's renderInContext behaves differently from CALayer.

Am I doing anything wrong in trying to capture the tiles?  Is my only solution to render the tiles individually myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, rather than trying to render the tiles into another view just for animation, I just created a new instance of `ImageScrollView`, and animated the original one and the new one together before deallocating the original one.